# insert variable into data request dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, python-requests

I am trying to build a simple record player with the spotify API and I would like to save the playlist id's in variables so it is easier to change or add in the future

```
import json 
import requests

spotify_user_id = "...."
sgt_peppers_id = "6QaVfG1pHYl1z15ZxkvVDW"  

class GetSongs:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_id=spotify_user_id
        self.spotify_token = ""
        self.sgt_peppers_id = sgt_peppers_id


    def find_songs(self):
        query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?
        device_id=......"


        headers={"Content.Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer 
{}".format(self.spotify_token)}
        data= '{"context_uri":"spotify:album:6QaVfG1pHYl1z15ZxkvVDW"}'

        response = requests.put(query, headers=headers, data=data)
```

I would like to be able to have it like this:
data= '{"context_uri":f"spotify:album:{sgt_peppers_id}"}'

but sadly it doesnt work and all the other methods for inserting variables into strings dont  work either. Hope somebody has the anser to this. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spotify API is expecting the request body to be `json`, which you're currently building by hand. But, it looks like you're using a misspelled header: `Content.Type` instead of `Content-Type` *(dot instead of dash)*.

Luckily, the python `requests` library can [encode python objects into json](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#:%7E:text=(url%2C-,json%3Dpayload,-)) for you and add the `Content-Type` headers automatically. It can also [add the parameters to the url](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) for you, so you don't have to create the `?query=string` manually.

```py
# We can add this to the string as a variable in the `json={...}` arg below
album_uri = "6QaVfG1pHYl1z15ZxkvVDW"

response = requests.put(
    "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play",  # url without the `?`
    params={"device_id": "..."},  # the params -- ?device_id=...
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {self.spotify_token}"},
    json={"context_uri": f"spotify:album:{album_uri}"},
)
```

Let the requests library do the work for you!

Comment: This worked amazingly!! I was able to make the code so much shorter and easier to modify and add to in the future, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Please mark this as the answer.